# Passing a mocked object as the instance in PHPUnit/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I'm mocking an object and writing a test like so...

```
public function test_mocked_object(){
    $purchase = new Purchase();
    $purchase_m = \Mockery::mock($purchase);
    $purchase_m->shouldReceive('internalMethod')->andReturn('GOLD');

    $purchase_m->testMethod('test');
}
```

`testMethod()` contains a call to `internalMethod()`, like so...

```
public function testMethod($string){
    $this->internalMethod();
}
```

... but by the time execution reaches the call to `$this->internalMethod()`, `$this` is now an instance of the original `$purchase` object, and not an instance of the `$purchase_m` mocked object.

Therefore, the function call to `$this->internalMethod()` does not return "GOLD" as we were hoping.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

hehe nevermind! Solved it.

```
$shpm \Mockery::mock(Purchase::class)->makePartial();
```

By creating a [partial mock](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#runtime-partial-test-doubles), you keep the instance intact when calling methods on it.

Hope this helps someone!